# Failed to upgrade 13.04 tp 13.10

Tags: upgrade

When updating to 13.10 I am getting the following error and cannot find a reference to it anywhere

```
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Your suggestions would be appreciated.

Ron

The following is the results of the suggestion

```
  1 # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted
 2  # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)]/ precise main restricted
 3  
 4  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
 5  # newer versions of the distribution.
 6  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
 7  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
 8  
 9  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
10  ## distribution.
11  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
12  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
13  
14  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
15  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
16  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
17  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring universe
18  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring universe
19  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
20  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
21  
22  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
23  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
24  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
25  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
26  ## security team.
27  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
28  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
29  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
30  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
31  
32  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
33  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
34  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
35  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
36  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
37  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
38  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
39  
40  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted
41  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted
42  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-security universe
43  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-security universe
44  deb http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-security multiverse
45  deb-src http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/ubuntu/ raring-security multiverse
46  
47  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
48  ## 'partner' repository.
49  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
50  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
51  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
52  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
53  
54  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
55  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
56  deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
57  deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
58  
59  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
60  # newer versions of the distribution.
61  
62  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
63  ## distribution.
64  
65  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
66  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
67  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
68  
69  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
70  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
71  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
72  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
73  ## security team.
74  
75  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
76  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
77  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
78  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
79  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
80  
81  
82  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
83  ## 'partner' repository.
84  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
85  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
86  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
87  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
88  
89  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
90  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list

 1  deb http://plex.r.worldssl.net/PlexMediaServer/ubuntu-repo lucid main

 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_plexmediaserver_ubuntu.list

 1  # deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/plexmediaserver/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf disabled on upgrade to raring

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stebbins-handbrake-releases-quantal.list

 1  # deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
 2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
```

After running the 2nd suggestions I got this error

W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386ls/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Open a terminal and execute the following command (copy-pate from here) `find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;` . Edit your question and paste the results there.

Answer (score 0):

As it will take too long to explain what to remove from this malformed file (sources.list), I will give you a set of commands that will:

1) Do a backup of your current sources.list

2) Move the sources.list.d folder and create a new one. Clean up.

3) Download a correct (generated) sources.list file and replace the old one.

4) Do a full system update , so all packages will be up to date.

Open a terminal and execute the following commands (copy-paste from here one by one)

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old 
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ~/sources.list.d-old/
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ 
sudo wget "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UUKLVKek" -O /etc/apt/sources.list 
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**If the update completes without errors**, reboot you PC and try to upgrade to 13.10.

> As Ubuntu 13.04 has been reached EOL
>   (End Of Life) the repositories will be moved  (I don't know when) on
>   [old.releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/), so the
>   above commands will not work in near future. For an EOL upgrade visit
>   the [community wiki - EOL
>   Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)